# How to reconcile newer workspace files with depot in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

I have a situation where my depot is saying it has the latest version of a bunch of different files but my local workspace actually has newer revisions. My tools (P4V and VS plugin) are incorrectly telling me that everything is up-to-date.

I can prove this is the case because if I *check out* the file, make no changes, and *submit*, the changes are committed and the history appears correct and *get latest* operations on other machines pull the correct version of the file.

This isn't really a viable solution as there could be many files that require this fix and I have no way of knowing I have fixed them all.

I believe the issue has come about due to occasionally working offline and (incorrectly) twiddling the read only flag on the file when I needed to make a change.

So my question:

**Is there a command (or similar) I can run that will look at my workspace files and see that there is a change that hasn't been committed. Essentially ignoring the 'reported' state of the file? Something like *sync* but in reverse?** This would allow me to 'force commit' all those files and get the depot in the correct state.

Comment: Just had a thought. What would the impact be if I checked out every file and then performed a 'revert if unchanged' command? Wouldn't this leave me with just the changed files checked out?

Comment: That would work but you still have to deal with files that were deleted that are still in the depot.  The next time you `p4 sync` those files would show up.  There's got to be a better way to `reconcile`.  I even considered just creating a fresh branch.

Answer (score 2):

The command you are looking for is called 'p4 reconcile'. Here's some background information: [Working Disconnected from the Perforce Server](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3481/).

Comment: Here's a direct link to the particular part of the page:  http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3481/#j_id0:j_id1:j_id289:j_id290:j_id313:j_id314:j_id321:j_id322:j_id565:j_id567:0:j_id568

The article shows a technique for older 2012.1 perforce users.